# cf login - credentials were rejected in Windows GIT runner as shell

Tags: git, cloud-foundry, runner, pcf

Unable to login to cf with cf login in GIT runner as shell

`$ cf login -a api.sys.xxx.pcf.xxx.com -u xxxxx -p xxxxx -o xxx -s xx --skip-ssl-validation`

```
API endpoint: api.sys.xxx.pcf.xxx.com
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.

API endpoint:   api.sys.xxx.pcf.xxx.com (API version: 2.103.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
FAILED
Unable to authenticate.
```

I am able to execute the same command and successfully authenticate with Windows Powershell. But with GIT-CICD yml file I am trying to execute the above command and not working.

```
Runner is configured in Windows as shell and shell = "Powershell"
below is the .toml file configuration
[[runners]]
  name = "Test PCF deployment"
  url = "https://Git Path"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "PowerShell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Any suggestions would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long-standing known issue that I think you're hitting.

> In Cygwin and Git Bash on Windows, interactive password prompts (in cf login) do not work (issue #171). Please use alternative commands (cf api and cf auth to cf login) to work around this.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#known-issues